# Echo array data turns all text into lowercase

Tags: php, mysql, sql, uppercase

I am having some problems fetching the array from my database properly.
All my text is being echoed in lowercase. While the text in the database is both lower & uppercase. How can make it fetch properly?
This is my actual SQL request:

```
$page = (int) (!isset($_GET['p'])) ? 1 : $_GET['p'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM newsfeed_status AS ns LEFT OUTER JOIN login AS lo ON ns.user = lo.id WHERE ns.status_deleted is null ORDER BY ns.status_id DESC";
$start = ($page * $limit) - $limit;
if( mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql)) > ($page * $limit) ){
$next = ++$page;
}
$query = mysql_query( $sql . " LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}");
?>
```

I use this to start a `while` statement:

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)): ?>
```

and here I echo the status text using this:

```
<?php echo $row['post']?>
```

**My input looks like this:**

> share my thoughts? i'll give you thoughts!

**When I want this:**

> Share my thoughts? I'll give you thoughts!

**This is my var_dump($row['post']); result:**

> share my thoughts? i'll give you thoughts!string(42) "share my
>   thoughts? i'll give you thoughts!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in order to debug this there are a couple of questions and steps to follow, first, where are you echoing your data? Maybe you are wrapping it in a `html` tag that has a `css` attribute like `text-transform: lowercase;`? Another thing would be to just use `var_dump($row['post'])` in order to see if its really comming case sensitive from the database. Please share your `html` and `css` as well so we can fully debug your issue.

After checking your question's edit, where the `var_dump` is, the problem seems to be in the database or maybe your css file. In your `php` code i've could not find anything that would make your test lowercase. Check your whole `css` and find `lowercase` (Just do a global search in your stylesheets for that word, maybe in your html or body css rules you are setting everything to lowercase.

Another question, What happens if you just write a string in your page?
Something like Hello, This is A Test STRING. Does it get lowercased as well?

Comment: Added var_dump, no lowercase in CSS.

Comment: I ran var_dump outside the following div: `<div id="bottom-status-post">`. Checked the CSS pointing to it. No text-transform in it. Possible bug?

Comment: EDIT: I found a css with lowercase in it. I use sepereate spreadsheets and somehow I managed to write it in the `colors.css`. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug further,

What happens when you just run the query in mysql?
Have you tried running the script with php command from command prompt/bash?